# How can I have xy coordinates in a grid that can't be used?

Tags: c#

How can I have xy coordinates that can't be used? Say I don't want xy (5,5) and (7,9) to ever be used. How can I do this?

```
x = random.Next(0, 20);
y = random.Next(0, 20);

// if xy coordinate is (5,5) or (7,9), keep trying the above to obtain a different xy value
```

When a xy coordinate is created how can I have certain coordinates not be usable?

Comment: What's a slot?  And what does it mean to reserve one?  Currently the code you've shown successfully instantiates a couple of integers and then generates two random numbers.  What isn't working?

Comment: what do you mean by "slot"? Do you mean a pair of random numbers? You could simply loop until the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Yes, I want to reserve certain random numbers so they cannot be used.

Comment: It would be nice if people would explain why they downthumbed the question. :P

Comment: @rotaercz: Because the question is unclear.  It alludes to context not explained in the question.  ("slots" and "reserve" mainly)  Anyway, if you don't want to use certain numbers then why not just compare the random number against the "reserved" ones and, if they match, generate another random number?

Comment: @David: I updated so the question is clearer.

Comment: Is the question not clear enough? I'm sincerely asking.

Comment: [We don't understand your goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); tell us what you are trying to achieve, not just how you have decided to do whatever it is that you haven't told us. And your edit removed information, now we have even less idea about what you are doing.

Comment: I removed 2 lines of code, which was the maxValue of random.Next(). It's not really important at all in the question and I thought it made the question clearer. The goal is to have a randomly generated xy coordinate, however it should not be an xy coordinate that is reserved (thus the 5,5 and 7.9 example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the creation until your condition is satisfied:

```
var forbidden = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
forbidden.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(5, 5));
forbidden.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(7, 9));
while(true)
{
    x = random.Next(0, 20);
    y = random.Next(0, 20);
    if(forbidden.All(t => x != t.Item1 || y != t.Item2)) break;
}
```

This way, the loop will only terminate if you have coordinates that are "allowed", i.e. reach the `break` statement.

Comment: This is really close to what I'm looking for. Is it possible to have a list of xy coordinates that shouldn't be used?

Comment: @rotaercz: I edited the answer. Just add the coordinates you want with `forbidden.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(/* x here */, /* y here */));`

Comment: This assumes you know all forbidden pairs before you generate your first pair. No way to tell if that is what the poster wanted...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking for a random number from 0 to (max slots) you could ask for a number to fill the *nth free time slot* and keep track of the free slots (e.g. using a boolean for each slot).

In the beginning `free time lots = max slots`, then `free time slots` decreases after each assignment. Walk through the slots - O(n) - and fill the nth free slot, n being the number returned by `Random.Next(0, freeSlots)`

Comment: Some example code would be great.